# How to expose a client s/w (like .exe, .bin etc) from a j2ee web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exe

We have a client application (different for each OS like windows, MAC etc.). Now we need to make the same available for download from our j2ee web application. We intend to freely distribute these executables/binaries i.e. without any authentication to the page that exposes them.
I have the following questions:
 1. What is the best secure way of doing so for any executable?
 2. If I have links to the executables/binaries on my unprotected page, which is the best location where I store them? On my web server, database, content management server or ...?
 3. Since I am exposing a .exe file, what are possible security threats that I might be exposing my j2ee web app to and how to avert all of them?

Comment: Put it on the webserver, it's not really common to include large binaries in the j2ee app. Also you don't have to redeploy the j2ee app, to update the binaries. As they can only download this binary, I would say it is no more threat then publishing an image.

Comment: What if I protect the web server resource with a CAPTCHA?
Will it provide some security against bot attacks?

Answer (score 0):

U could look at using a no-sql document-type database, like MongoDB. IMO, its easier to manage (access, update, security, scaling) of items stored in a database. Our company is looking at migrating such files from the file system to a db.